# HTML5 Canvas - How to draw rectangle over image in canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

Actually, I am able to do it using `img.onload` function. Something I got from '[HTML5 Canvas - How to Draw a line over an image background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623678/html5-canvas-how-to-draw-a-line-over-an-image-background)'. But I need to draw image without using `img` from `onload` function which is like this:

```
    var imagePaper = new Image();


        imagePaper.onload = function(){


            context.drawImage(imagePaper,100, 20, 500,500);
        };

      imagePaper.src = "images/main_timerand3papers.png";
}
```

But I want to able draw rectangle over canvas simply attaching img src above canvas, just as:

```
<body>  
<img id="scream" src="my.jpg" alt="The Scream" width="220" height="277">

<p>Canvas:</p>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500" >
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```

But I'm unable to draw line over img in canvas, either img is drawing or shape is hiding behind. This is my full code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>  
 <head>  
 <title>Playing YouTube video on HTML5 canvas</title>  
 <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />  
 <style type="text/css">  
body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      } 
 </style>  
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 </head>  
 <body>  
<img id="scream" src="my.jpg" alt="The Scream" width="220" height="277">

<p>Canvas:</p>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500" >
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
  <script>  
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
var img=document.getElementById("scream");
ctx.drawImage(img,10,10);  
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

      context.beginPath();
      context.rect(188, 50, 200, 100);
      context.fillStyle = 'yellow';
      context.fill();
      context.lineWidth = 7;
      context.strokeStyle = 'black';
      context.stroke();
  </script>  
 </body>  
 </html>
```

Comment: looks to me like you just need a `position: absolute` style on the canvas element so that it's placed directly on top of the `<img>`, and do it without drawing the image into the canvas - i.e. just use compositing.

Comment: Actually, i was just wondering to do matematically functions,that' why it doesn't need

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Because you are not waiting for the image to load first. In your `script` add an `window.onload()`

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var img = document.getElementById('scream');

  context.drawImage(img, 10, 10);

  context.beginPath();
  context.rect(188, 50, 200, 100);
  context.fillStyle = 'yellow';
  context.fill();
  context.lineWidth = 7;
  context.strokeStyle = 'black';
  context.stroke();
}
</script>
```

What is happening is it's trying to draw the image before it loaded, doing `window.onload` will call the code once the entire document is loaded (such as images). Otherwise it may display no image or draw it out of line.

Answer (score 3):

I tried this same approach of using ***window.onload()*** and it worked until I tried it using **Microsoft Edge** browser. A solution to that which worked for me was to attach an ***onload*** handler to the image, such as:

```
image.onload = function ()
{
    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
}
```

then it worked perfectly.