# How to make canvas line drawings above image?

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas, z-index

Basically, I'm creating a matching game. When I select an item(e.g. pear as seen in picture), it will translate to the right. However, it will end up being on top of the line drawn on the canvas. I want the line to be on top of the image and not the other way round.

I've tried using z-index for canvas to be greater than img but it does not work. Any idea how to fix this?

[image]

**HTML**

```
<table class="first">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <ul class="firstleft">
      /*some images to be filled here*/
      </ul>
    </td>
    <td>
      <canvas id="myCanvas" resize></canvas>
    </td>
    <td>
      <ul class="firstright">
      /*some images to be filled here*/
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
img {
   z-index: 1;
}
canvas {
   z-index: 20;
}
```

**JS**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
ctx.lineWidth = 6;
ctx.strokeStyle = "#333";
/* Drawing part using an example*/
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(100, 250);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(150, 100, 350, 100, 400, 250);
ctx.stroke();
```

Comment: set that **image** `z-index` to `-1`

Comment: hmm. still doesn't work

Comment: Just check this out...  may be it will help you    ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623678/html5-canvas-how-to-draw-a-line-over-an-image-background                           and this one also              http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26902084/html5-canvas-how-to-draw-rectangle-over-image-in-canvas?lq=1

Comment: image's z-index should be -1 and lines z-index should be 1

Comment: @AkshayKumar Well I think it's different in this case because I'm not drawing on top of an image. I'm drawing lines on a canvas and I'm translating the image which just so happens to come across the line. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @abhayvyas been there done that

Comment: You are doing everything so wrong I dont even know where to start

Comment: @CHEWWWWWWWWWW. A Suggestion: Consider refactoring your code to have all game elements drawn on the canvas where its much easier to coordinate game elements, user mouse events and game connection lines.

Answer (score 0):

in that case it works

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('demo'), /// canvas element
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),            /// context
    line = new Line(ctx),                     /// our custom line object
    img = new Image;                          /// the image for bg

ctx.strokeStyle = '#fff';                     /// white line for demo

/// start image loading, when done draw and setup 
img.onload = start;
img.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/O712qpO.jpg';

function start() {
    /// initial draw of image
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, demo.width, demo.height);

    /// listen to mouse move (or use jQuery on('mousemove') instead)
    canvas.onmousemove = updateLine;
}
```